# Running Jupyter Notebook from a miniconda3 docker image

Tags: docker, conda, miniconda

I am using the [continuumio/miniconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/~/dockerfile/) base image to build a docker image with my `conda` environment, my own package and finally trying to start a Jupyter Notebook.

This image builds fine:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
RUN git clone https://github.com/myself/myrepo.git
RUN conda env create --file myrepo/environment.yml
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate myenv && pip install ./myrepo" ]
# To build matplotlib.pyplot font cache
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate myenv && ipython -c 'import matplotlib.pyplot'" ]
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "-c", ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate myenv && jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root" ]
```

However, upon starting the image I only get a bash prompt.

Could you point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how do you run the container? you might need to override its entrypoint